# How to schedule a notification to a specific time?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, alarmmanager, reminders

I used the code below to schedule a notification to a specified delay. Can someone please tell me what changes i should make to the code so as to schedule the notification to a specified time,say 9:15 AM.

```
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    int delay=10000;
    long futureInMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + delay;
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, futureInMillis, pendingIntent);
```